# Angular 2 clickable <td> with contents

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table, mouseclick-event

So I have the following snippet for a table:

```
<td style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onClickConfiguration($event, pr)">
    <div *ngFor="let obj of parseConfiguration(pr)" style="white-space: normal">
        <label>{{obj.key}}</label>: {{obj.value}}
    </div>
</td>
```

What I basically want is to make the entire `<td>` clickable including the contents. The cell contents are like below:

[image: <td> contents]

So wherever I click I need to trigger the event. Now I guess I could apply `(click)` everywhere  but I guess that's not the best approach.

Comment: Applying a `(click)` to the `<td>` already does what you describe. An event triggered on descendants of an element bubble to that element

Comment: Normally yes, if I insert any simple element there it bubbles up. However, it looks like the ngFor directive does something strange.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the problem

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? What is `pr`? You pass it to `onClickConfiguration`.

Comment: no error in the console, `pr` is just an object I have previously initialized. If I click on the padding between `<td>` and `<div>` it works fine and the MouseEvent is logged from `onClickConfiguration`.
Or if for example, the contents of `parseConfiguration(pr)` is empty and you have an empty array, it works normally if you click on the empty `<td>`.
But if you actually click on the `<div>` `<label>` or text that is created by the interpolation it doesn't work.